# set Property value automatically in app engine Model Class

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

How to set the value of a Model property from inside the model (datastore ndb.Model)?

```
class Note(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    depth = ndb.IntegerProperty()

    def _calculate_depth(self):
        self.depth = len(self.key.parent().pairs())

note = Note( parent=ndb.Key('Note', 'main', 'Todo', 'task1') , content='whatever')
note.put()
```

What I'm looking for is that when the create new note calculate_depth method is run, it sets the value of depth Property

Solution :)

```
class Note(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    depth = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: len(self.key.parent().pairs()))


note = Note( parent=ndb.Key('Note', 'main', 'Todo', 'task1') , content='whatever')
note.put()
```

Comment: what I was looking for is ComputedProperty, Thanks to @Jimmy Kane I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the previus thing.

What you are looking for is post [PUT hooks.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass?hl=nl#Model__post_put_hook)

I see that at your function `_calculate_depth` you use the value of the key of the entity. Then the entity not only needs to be created but also written in the ndb to key a key.

If you want that to happen "automatically" then Model__post_put_hook is what you need

Comment: @KAl-Mazrouai than please check the correct for this answer and welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: I think the pervious answer is working as well, it will be helpful for other to keep both solutions

Comment: @KAl-Mazrouai nice to hear. App engine has some more nice features. Look also for structured properties